# コミュニティのために一緒に: コミュニティにどのような問題を感じていますか?

Tags: 討議

[Sieg](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/7676/sieg)、[aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)、[cubick](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3060/cubick)に翻訳してくれてありがとう

---

あなたがそれについて何も知らないならば、何かを学ぶことは不可能です：どの程度の知識を持ち、何が出来るかが非常に重要です。プログラミング知識を作成し、蓄積し、そして維持する問題は世界中で同じですが、異なる言語では異なる形態を取ります。これは特定のコミュニティの文化や歴史の違いによるものです。本家 Stack Overflowを例に見ると、サイトを立ち上げる前に2つの重大な問題がありました。

- 構造化された集合知はありませんでした。 質問に対する答えを見つけるのは非常に困難で、多くの時間がかかりました。
- 検索結果には、そのサイトへのアクセスに対し対価を支払うまでコンテンツを表示しない有料サイトのリンクで埋めつくされました。

例外はなく、誰もが苦労しました。英語圏のコミュニティの転換点は、人々が一緒にこれらの問題に取り組み始めたときに起こりました。彼らはStack Overflowを立ち上げ、CC-BY-SAライセンスの下でサイトに関する知識を集め始めました。

スタック・オーバーフロー は、日本語の主要な知識源の1つになる可能性が高いと思います。本家 Stack Overflow が英語を話す開発者の生活の中でどのようになってきたかに似ています。この成功を掴むために、私たちは協力して日本語のコミュニティ全体の重大な問題を解決する必要があります。この道の最初の1歩は私達が感じるコミュニティの問題を集めることです。それから、私たちが本当に解決したいものを議論し選択します。次に、選択した問題をコミュニティのために一緒に解決します。

「素晴らしい道は小さな一歩から始まります。」私たちは今すぐ旅を始めることをお勧めします！ 
あなたやあなたの同僚が感じるコミュニティの問題についてあなたの考えを共有してください。分析の過程を簡略化するために、いくつかの質問を用意しました。これらの質問に答える形で、コミュニティの問題についてのあなたの考えを記入してください。

**注**: 以下の質問の「コミュニティ」とは、日本語を話すソフトウェア開発者全般を意味し、当サイト(スタック・オーバーフロー)に限られた話ではありません。

1. プログラミングに関する日本語の回答をオンライン上で探す時に何らかの問題に直面しますか？どのような時に最もフラストレーションを感じますか？どのようにすれば問題を改善することができるでしょうか？
2. 日本語でのプログラミングに関する質問への回答は、現在どのサイトで見つけることができますか？そのサイトを使用するにあたり何か問題がありますか？どのようにその問題を解決することができるでしょうか？
3. 回答を探す時、何に最も長く時間をかけますか？このプロセスはどのように改善されると思いますか？
4. 日本語を話すプログラマーが経験するごく一般的な問題とはどのようなものですか？
5. 日本語コミュニティでオープンな知識ベースを構築することを妨げるものはありますか？どうすればこの問題を解決できるでしょうか？
6. あなたは同僚にプログラミングに関する質問を「オフライン」で聞きますか？どのようなプロセスで聞きますか？どのようにオフラインで質問するプロセスを改善することができるでしょうか？

同僚を招待して、討議に参加してください。
全体は部分の総和に勝ります。
（アリストテレスの言葉：各個人で動くよりも全員で動いたほうが強いの意）

---

もし、匿名でこれらの質問に回答したい場合は [Google Forms](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSenfYuoKP6qon8fDvDS7A9zR-w57XBX6OeO8zlk27U8313ifw/viewform) を利用してください。
今後、匿名のレビューを考慮して議論していきます。

---

関連：[2019年7月時点でのサマリー](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331531/314875)

Comment: ur welcome! ところでGoogleフォームの方にはフリーコメント欄がありますが、6項目以外にも気になる点があればこちらでも回答しても大丈夫でしょうか？
GoogleForms has any additional comments, but can i write it freely here too?

Comment: @Sieg はい、してください。

Comment: 5番の "a free knowledge base" は「無料の」ではなく「自由の」とか、フリーソフトウェアの意味での「フリー」かもしれません。

Answer (score 5):

### 1. プログラミングに関する日本語の回答をオンライン上で探す時に何らかの問題に直面しますか？

日本語で検索していた頃は、たくさんのブログ記事が検索にひっかかり、その中から有益な情報を見つける作業をしていた気がします。掲示板は少なかったです。ブログ記事が互いにリンクしていてネットワークを為しており、それらを全部タブで開いて悩んでいた気がします。どの情報が良いかも判断できず、書いてあった何かしらのワークアラウンドで解決できても、なぜ解決できたのかの理由が分からないこともしばしばありました。

最近自分で問題解決するときは英語で検索しています。英語が分かるなら英語の方が話者人口が多い分情報も多く、公式情報も英語のことが多いからです。ただ Google は検索結果をパーソナライズしており、英語で検索しても日本語記事を上位に出してきます。英語記事を見たくて英語で検索しているのにそうならないので個人的にフラストレーションを感じており、英語記事が優先される設定と日本語記事が優先される設定の検索窓を使い分けたりしています。逆に言うと、日本語記事に満足な情報量があるならこの問題は解決します。

### 2. 日本語でのプログラミングに関する質問への回答は、現在どのサイトで見つけることができますか？

少し質問意図とは異なるのかもしれませんが、自分が日本語で検索するときよく引っかかるウェブサイトをグループ分けしてみました。

- 個人のブログ記事：未だに多いです。特に、ニッチな分野だとブログ記事頼りになりがちです。
- [Qiita](https://qiita.com/)：もともと質問サービスとしてできたサービスでしたが、すぐに技術ブログ記事投稿サービスに変わり、一定の地位を得ています。通常のブログと違い第三者が編集リクエストを送る機能が整っているので、細かい間違いは修正されていることが多いです。一方で中身の薄い記事が多いと批判されることもあります。
- [teratail](https://teratail.com/) / [SOja](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/) / [Quora](https://jp.quora.com/)：それぞれ微妙に違いますがどれも Q&A サービスです。
- ウェブ上で技術記事の連載を行っているサイトの記事：運営側が選んだ、一定の技術を持った人に書いてもらっている場合が多く、上手くマッチすれば大変助けになることが書いてあることがあります。[gihyo.jp](http://gihyo.jp/)、[@IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/) など。
- 初心者向け技術解説ブログを書いているウェブサイト：日本では、技術解説ブログを書いて閲覧数を稼ぎ、付随するサービス（大人向けプログラミング塾など）への流入を狙うウェブサイトがいくつか存在します。個人的にこのようなサービスのブログ記事が本質的な助けになった経験は少ないです。
- プラットフォームごとの質問フォーラム。たとえば [Ubuntu 日本語フォーラム](https://forums.ubuntulinux.jp/viewtopic.php?id=6953)や [TeX フォーラム](https://oku.edu.mie-u.ac.jp/tex/)など。

### 3. 回答を探す時、何に最も長く時間をかけますか？このプロセスはどのように改善されると思いますか？

公式ドキュメントを読む時間です。これはある程度しょうがないかなと思っています。

### 4. 日本語を話すプログラマーが経験するごく一般的な問題とはどのようなものですか？

一般的かどうかあまり自信がないですが：

- 英語圏で話題になった最新技術が日本語圏で話題になるまでに少しラグがあること。
- CJK 文字に関する文字化けなど、日本語だからこその挙動は日本語と中国語以外の情報が少ないこと。

### 5. 日本語コミュニティでフリーの知識ベースを構築することを妨げるものはありますか？

（すぐには思いつきませんでした。）

### 6. あなたは同僚にプログラミングに関する質問を「オフライン」でどのように聞きますか？

- Slack の分報チャンネルでぽつぽつ呟くと反応が来る。
- 1対1の短いミーティングを設定して聞く。
- ランチ時などのフリートークで話題にする。

今まで、オフラインでのコミュニケーションに問題を感じたことはあまりありません。

Answer (score 4):

一部ここに書くか、指標に書くか迷いましたが……こちらで。
項目が多いので、とても長くなってしまいました……。

---

1. 日本語で疑問を探す際の問題

今でこそ、調べることに難しさや問題はそれほど感じませんが、初学の時は大変でした。

まず少し昔の話では、そもそものドキュメントが英語だったりして
誤訳や解釈違いで間違った認識をブログで拡散されている方もいました。
その情報の真偽を自分では判定できず、鵜呑みにして「実は本質は違いました」ということもありました。

また、日本ではメジャーでない技術や、最新動向については日本語の記事が少なく、
中々、英語圏の目的のフォーラムや記事にすら辿り着けないことがありました。

これらの問題はそれぞれ目的とするキーワードの把握能力、"語彙力"とでも言うんでしょうか？
そのようなノウハウや、検索力が足りないと中々解決しなくてモドカシイ思いをしました。

そのため、新しい分野を切り開くためには先人の知恵を借りるか、四苦八苦しながら進むしかなく、
英語の原文ドキュメントを読めすらしない初学者にとっては、とても厳しい環境であることをヒシヒシと感じます。

---

2. 日本語圏の主な疑問の解決サイト

最近は質問スレとかあんまり見ないイメージですが、2ch(現5ch)とかもありました。
ただし、辛辣な方が多く、「技術者怖い」なイメージが先走っていた印象です。
なので、質問に二の足を踏むこともしばしばありました。
あと、もう現在では閉鎖されているようですが、
ACCESSとかでデータベース作った時は、accessclubにもお世話になりましたね。
以下ズラズラとサイトをあげます。

※先人さまのブログやTwitterなどのSNSです。
　ブログで詳細に纏めてくれたり、気になるネタをボソリとTwitterで零したり、
　色々参考にさせてもらっています。

- 開発者個人の記事
- SNS(Twitterなど)

※集合知的な自分が考える三大サイトは以下ですかね？

- StackOverflow ja
- Qiita
- teratail

※雑多な質問が多いイメージですが、拾い上げてくれる人は少なからずいます。

- OKWave
- Yahoo知恵袋

※以下は一例ですが、CMSやツールについては専用フォーラムがあることがあります。

- Wordpress日本語フォーラム

---

3. 疑問を解決する際に一番時間をかけること。

昔：疑問を解決するための検索語を見つけること。
今：質問するための資料を推敲すること。

---

4. 日本語話者の開発者で起こる一般的な問題。

英語力ぅ……ですかねぇ……。
日本語資料がないとやっぱり大変ですよね。
今は素直に英語が読めない訳して！とか、コレコレが分からないで質問すれば日本語化してくれるような気がします。

---

5. 日本語コミュニティで無料の知識ベースを構築することを妨げるものはありますか？

日本人の性なのかもしれないですけど、採点が加点方式ではなく、減点方式なんですよね。
非難されるのを恐れる余り、匿名性を強める(1質問1アカウント)か、減点されて「もう使うのやめよ」ってなるイメージが強いです。
また、一度決めたルールにストイック過ぎるのも問題に感じています。
コミュニティで作るルールなので矛盾が発生してもその都度可否を決めても良い気がするんですよね。
懐大きく受け入れて、もう少し柔軟になっていいのでは？と考えています。

---

6. あなたは同僚にプログラミングに関する質問を「オフライン」でどのように聞きますか？

開発形態にも寄りますがペアプログラミングしているなら聞けないことは無いですね。
それ以外では、基本的に雰囲気によると思うので、質問しやすい雰囲気が出来ていることではないでしょうか？
これはオンラインにも言えることで、質問しづらい雰囲気の場所で質問を行いたいと思う人はいないと思います。

---

7. そのほか感じること

正直な話、直感的に使い方が分かるものに対して"取り扱い説明書"を読む人は少ないと思います。
つまり何が言いたいかというと、質問できて、回答できる環境が一目でフォームだと分かるのであれば、
METAやヘルプを最初から読む人は少ないのではないか？ということです。
コミュニティによって日々ルールや、方針を決めていますが、
それが、信用度の低いユーザに伝わるかは別の問題だと思っています。

一方で、teratailの質問テンプレート良いですね。
現在不足情報があれば、コメントで追加情報を促して、コメントに書かれた補足を質問を編集して追記して……。
とっても無駄だとおもいます。質問テンプレートがあったら省ける工程なのになぁと感じます。

アカウント登録しても2度目はないユーザが多いです。
初利用者がヘルプを見なくても、ある程度のルールが分かると良いのではないかと考えています。
（もしくは、コミュニティがもう少し寛容になるか……かな？と思ってます。）

Comment: 個人的に、初心者ユーザーは[ツアー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tour)で分かる範囲を把握していれば充分だと思っています。メタで議論したりヘルプに書いたりしたことは、信用度が高くなって権限を持ったユーザーが困ったときにどうするかを考えるためにあるような気がしていて、だからメタで充分なのかな、と。初心者に提示するための分かりやすい文章としてヘルプセンターやFAQがあると思っています。

Comment: 質問テンプレートの機能自体は[昔から提案されていた](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16843/341401)のですが、自由な質問の仕方を妨げるとかの理由で実装されていなかった経緯があった記憶があります（出典を見つけられませんでした、すいません）。ただここ1年くらいは事情が変わっていて、英語版Stack Overflowで ["Ask a Question" Wizard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369682/5989200) がテストされていて、[こんな感じの統計が公開されています](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/363051/5989200)。日本語版でも試して欲しいという機能の要求をメタ投稿するのはアリだと思います :)

Comment: メタで決まったことを、事情が変わったことに応じて再決議し始めることは全然許されているのですが、そもそもメタに投稿するユーザーが少なくてあまり上手く回っていない印象です……。

Comment: 参考までに、よく見かける「FW/ツールのバージョンなど」というテンプレートはどうやらteratailで用意されているものみたいです。

Comment: そうですよね、過去にも再決議はあったような気がしますし、コミュニティ主導な以上、コミュニティの総意が是となればOKだとは自分も思ってます。言われて考えたのは、METAを利用されているユーザは比較的柔軟な気がします。＝「METAが活発でないのが問題？」とはいえどうしたら良いのかはパッと思いつかないのですが…